# How to display image with Bokeh’s low-level bokeh.models.ImageRGBA interface?

Tags: python, bokeh

I could display image with Bokeh's high-level interface [figure.image_rgba](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/image_rgba.html)
but how to use low-level interface ImageRGBA to do this if i need complete control to it ?

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ImageRGBA

N = 20
img = np.empty((N,N), dtype=np.uint32)
view = img.view(dtype=np.uint8).reshape((N, N, 4))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        view[i, j, 0] = int(i/N*255)
        view[i, j, 1] = 158
        view[i, j, 2] = int(j/N*255)
        view[i, j, 3] = 255

p = figure(tooltips=[("x", "$x"), ("y", "$y"), ("value", "@image")])
p.x_range.range_padding = p.y_range.range_padding = 0

# must give a vector of images
# p.image_rgba(image=[img], x=0, y=0, dw=10, dh=10) 
im = ImageRGBA(image=[img], x=0, y=0, dw=10, dh=10)
p.add_glyph(im)
show(p)
```

And I get :

```
ValueError: failed to validate ImageRGBA(id='1740', ...).image: expected an element of either String, Dict(Enum('expr', 'field', 'value', 'transform'), Either(String, Instance(Transform), Instance(Expression), Float)) or Float, got [array([[4278230528, 4279016960, 4279868928, 4280720896, 4281572864,
       ......
        4290748146, 4291600114, 4292386546, 4293238514, 4294090482]],
      dtype=uint32)]
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You can't pass data direclty to a glyph model. You have to put the data in a data source, and configure the glyph to use the data source. There are many complete examples here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/branch-3.0/examples/models

Answer (score 0):

Thank @bigreddot. Here is modified code

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ImageRGBA, ColumnDataSource

N = 20
img = np.empty((N,N), dtype=np.uint32)
view = img.view(dtype=np.uint8).reshape((N, N, 4))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        view[i, j, 0] = int(i/N*255)
        view[i, j, 1] = 158
        view[i, j, 2] = int(j/N*255)
        view[i, j, 3] = 255

p = figure(tooltips=[("x", "$x"), ("y", "$y"), ("value", "@image")])
p.x_range.range_padding = p.y_range.range_padding = 0

im_glyph = ImageRGBA(x=0, y=0, dw=10, dh=10)

im_source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    image = [img]
))
p.add_glyph(im_source,im_glyph)
show(p)
```